# Finding the area underneath y = x^4 in the domain 2 ≤ x ≤ 4 by using a Monte Carlo Method

Tags: java, random, montecarlo

In my approach, I will use a hypothetical rectangle with co-ordinates `(2,0)` , `(4,0)`, `(2, 256)` and `(4, 256)`. I will generate random xy co-ordinates within this rectangle and find the ratio between the number of co-ordinates that fall within the region defined by `y ≤ x^4` and the number of co-ordinates that fall within the entire rectangle. Multiplying this by the area of the rectangle should give me the area under the graph.

**I am struggling to generate random decimal xy co-ordinates in the defined rectangle. Any help would be much appreciated :)**

I have only just started integration in school so my knowledge in this area is quite narrow as of now.

Here is my code:

```
public class IntegralOfX2 {

    public static double randDouble(double min, double max) {
        min = 2;
        max = 4;
        Random rand = new Random();
           double randomNum;
        randomNum = min + rand.nextDouble((max - min) + 1); // an error keeps occuring here

        return randomNum;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double x = 0; // x co-ordinate of dart
        double y = 0; // y co-ordinate of dart
        int total_darts = 0; // the total number of darts
        int success_darts = 0; // the number of successful darts
        double xmax = 4;
        double xmin = 2;
        double ymax = 256;
        double ymin = 0;
        double area = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < 400000000; i++) {
         //   x = randDouble(xmin, xmax);
         //   y = randDouble(ymin, ymax);


          x = xmin + (Math.random() * ((xmax - xmin) + 1));
          y = ymin + (Math.random() * ((ymax - ymin) + 1));

                    total_darts++;


            if (y <= (x * x * x * x)) {
                success_darts++;
            }

        }


       double ratio = (double)success_darts/(double)total_darts;
       area = ratio * 512;
       System.out.println(area);

    }
}
```

Comment: @RC. 400 million is ok, 4 billion is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> randomNum = min + rand.nextDouble((max - min) + 1); // an error keeps occuring here

This is an error because no such method exists. What you may want is

```
public static double randDouble(double min, double max) {
    return min + Math.random() * (max - min + Math.ulp(max));
}
```

You can drop the Math.ulp but it is the closest to adding 1 for a random integer.

For large number of samples, you could use an even distribution e.g.

```
int samples = 100000;
double spacing = (max - min) / spacing;
for (int i = 0; i < samples; i++) {
    double x = min + (i + 0.5) * spacing;
    // use x as an input.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, my answer still seems to be extremely inaccurate. While the correct answer is 198.4, my estimate is roughly 302. Are there any errors in my logic that I should fix?

Comment: @Abhinav I can't see where you are calling this method in your code. I suggest you use it.

Comment: Ohhh yea I commented it out earlier. Thanks for pointing that out. My estimate is now 198.3 with the method! Thanks again!

Comment: @Abhinav the problem was most likely the extra `+1` which only applies for integer ranges. This is needed because you get a value which is slightly less than the upper bound, for a double this means a ~ 1 in 1e16 error (too small to notice) but for an integer, it means you never get the maximum value otherwise.

Comment: Yea that makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing this on a bounded interval, you can generally get a lower variance estimate of the area by using Monte Carlo sampling of the average height of your function.  Average height times the base is the area.  In pseudocode:

```
def f(x) {
    return x**4
}

range_min = 2
range_max = 4
range = range_max - range_min
sample_size = 100000
sum = 0
loop sample_size times {
    sum += f(range_min + range * U) // where U is a Uniform(0,1) random number
}
estimated_area = range * (sum / sample_size)
```

Comment: That is an interesting way to approach it. I'll try it out. Thanks!